# What's the fastest way to check if a username is available with a huge dataset?

Tags: php, mysql, redis

I'm looking for the fastest/most efficient way to search if a given username is available from a set of tens of millions of usernames. At the moment I'm using a normal MySQL SELECT query that runs every key press, but I'm not happy with the performance. I'm using indexing, partitioning, etc and I know that MySQL can be optimized to be very fast, but I also know that there are better solutions.

So what's the fastest username search:

- Redis EXISTS command
- Elasticsearch
- Something else

Ex: how does Gmail search across billions of email addresses when registering. How does Facebook do it? I assume they don't just run an SQL query.

I'm looking for a practical solution for a PHP app.

Right now I'm just using a very basic select:

```
SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = $username LIMIT 1
```

The username column has a unique index on it

Comment: What is wrong with an SQL query on a unique index? It should be O(logN) if done correctly.

Comment: @Dharman It can be even less than that depending on the indexing method employed.

Comment: I need millisecond-level speed.

Comment: @tadman what do you mean by "indexing method"? I'm just searching by one value and indexing that column. Across a table with 100 million rows it's 150 milliseconds (indexed). I need something closer to 1ms.

Comment: Why are you checking on every key press?

Comment: If your query takes 150ms to run your table isn't indexed properly, your server isn't tuned properly, or your hardware is woefully inadequate for the task at hand. I have production systems with billions of records and testing the presence of a `UNIQUE` key is near zero time. Some databases, like Postgres, have multiple indexing methods for your data and you can pick the one that performs best in your use case.

Comment: @tomschmidt what kind of query are you using? An exists query should take less time than a normal select; it can stop on the first match, rather than continuing on to collect all matches. Also, from my limited acquaintance with php; if you're checking every keypress, you're not actually doing that with php.

Comment: @tadman regardless, isn't 150ms very nearly  too fast to even be perceived by most people? Given that 100ms is perceived as "instantaneous" https://www.pubnub.com/blog/how-fast-is-realtime-human-perception-and-technology/

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton gamers would disagree about 100ms being "instantaneous", but expecting a username lookup to have the responsiveness of a first person shooter seems a bit unrealistic to me.

Comment: @Uueerdo Yeah I would agree, playing a game is a lot different than browsing a website with regards to expected rendering/loading times.

Comment: @Uueerdo I'm using a SELECT with limit 1, so it also stops on the 1st match.

Comment: You might want to add your current query/code to the question. Is your database on the same server as the code checking user names? How are you measuring your current performance?

Comment: @Uueerdo good idea, I just did it

Comment: I wouldn't count on `COUNT(*)` being as fast as `LIMIT 1` (no pun intended); have you tried something like `SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=$username) AS found`? Due to the way aggregation works, that COUNT might load the table data; the EXISTS query probably only needs to inspect the index.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I was using COUNT at first but now I'm using select with limit 1. I'll try your version as well.

Comment: Please do not concatenate PHP variables into SQL as shown in the example. Data must be separate from SQL statements!

Comment: Yes, I'm using prepared statements in the actual code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree you should try and stick it all in RAM (e.g. Redis).

But if you don't want to go the whole way, I do the following: store the list somewhere slow (e.g. S3 or a SQL database). Next, make a Bloom filter (there stuff on wikipedia on that, and there's a nifty Redis module that you can use - https://oss.redislabs.com/redisbloom) from that list.

Now, BF tells will never give you a false negative so you can efficiently check with it whether a username is available. Sometimes, however, the BF will report a username as unavailable (false positive) and you have decide if you can live with that.

Answer (score 0):

Load list into an associative array. Test presence of key. Done. "Tens of millions" is not a lot of data these days. It fits in RAM.

If you are short on memory and don't mind an astronomically small chance of a false positive, you can use SHA2-256 hashes instead of the full value. These are only 40 bytes hex-encoded, 20 bytes in their raw form. Checking if a hash key has been indexed is trivial, even *O(1)* time in many cases.

> Remember this is only relevant if you're dealing with peak loads in excess of 1000 queries per second. Don't prematurely optimize this. Most databases can do a username test in basically zero time, it's not even hard, and doing a thousand tests a second is not going to break your server.

If you do have a *measurable performance problem* then you can always explore indexing options. [MySQL supports different index types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html): `BTREE` or `HASH`. These perform differently.

Comment: I've considered that; however: is checking if a value exists in an array going to be faster than doing a search done by a DB engine? I'm aware of premature optimization, but currently this check is taking 100-200ms and I need to bring it down closer to 1ms or less.

Comment: As far as I can see, InnoDB only supports Btree indices and I'm using InnoDB.

Comment: It still shouldn't be this slow. This may be a question for the [DBA site](http://dba.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0):

Your example mention companies that use high-end systems. Obviously not any system can do that, and here is why:

Let's assume how a gigantic company address any username among billions:

There is a service, probably written in C, not even C++

It is deployed at a Unix or Linux cluster

There is also another service acts as health checker of the first one that checks every e.g. second a standard username and password

The service loads all data (usually username and password) in memory

When that data changes at its source, it is called to adopt changes, this is triggered from the data source

When a call is needed for data (our case), there are 2(minimum) asynchronous calls to two copies of the health checker (to avoid service-dead delays)that the primary service is alive

When any health checker replies ok, the call to the main service (of the checker) takes place, and verifies or not username and/or password requested.

The caller then continuous according to reply.

Concluding, whatever solution as close as possible to this works fast. A memory 'db' like redis as mentioned above is somewhat close - somewhat means close enough considering the differences. If a colossal company gets a performance of 10 and a simple website gets a performance of 8-9 using similar practices following same principles with costs adjusted to each company size, than i believe is a successful choice to do.